# Why table column headers change their width&

Tags: sapui5

I open one table in the dialog window. And it looks like this:
[Normal table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xy8Tj.png)

But if I close the dialog and reopen it, table column headers becomes more narrow like this:
[Strange table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPvXQ.png)

When I resize column width, headers become normal.

I use code from example SAPUI5 Explored | Grid Table 
(sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.ui.table.sample.Basic/code/View.view.xml)

```
<t:Table
            rows="Data>/Table}"
            class="sapUiSmallMargin"
            selectionMode="None"
            enableSelectAll="false"
            visibleRowCount="17">
            <t:columns>
                <t:Column
                    showFilterMenuEntry="false"
                    showSortMenuEntry="false"
                    width="3rem">
                    <Label text="Num" />
                    <t:template>
                        <Text text="{Data>Row}"/>
                    </t:template>
                </t:Column>
                ...
```

And I can't understand, what is the problem. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across this myself as well in certain browsers (Chrome), but not in others (such as IE11).

I believe that this is a browser-specific SAPUI5 rendering problem, and not a mistake in your coding.

If you do not set the width of the column manually, it will probably work just fine. If this is unacceptable, your could manually have the table to rerender once (just like what happens when you drag the width of the column).

Comment: I have this problem in Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m, but Firefox Nighty 51.0a1 and IE 11.0.9600.18314 show the table with "shifted" headers immediately when I open app. 
Now I change width of the first column mhen open dialog and all seems good. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it! If it answered your question, please select it as the correct answer.